# Skipping the dependencies of a target which is skipped due to "unless"

Tags: ant

I have an ant file like this:

```
<project name="test" basedir="." default="build">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="/data/build/scripts/ant-contrib-0.6.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <property name="target" value="/tmp/target.file" />

    <target name="build" depends="checkDone,fullBuild,noBuild" >
        <echo message="Build process completed for ${target}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="checkDone" >
        <available file="${target}" property="done"/>
    </target>

    <target name="noBuild" if="done" >
        <echo message="Build process skipped, ${target} already done" />
    </target>

    <target name="fullBuild" depends="step1,step2" unless="done" >
        <echo message="Build process executed for ${target}" />
    </target>

    <target name="step1" >
        <echo message="Executing step1" />
    </target>

    <target name="step2" >
        <echo message="Executing step2" />
    </target>

</project>
```

TL;DR: if the file is there, I want to execute "noBuild", and if it is not I want to execute "fullBuild" which is made of step1 and step2.

The question is: if the file is already there, "fullBuild" is skipped, but step1 and step2 are not...: here is the log:

```
Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on June 2 2005
Buildfile: /data/build/scripts/test.ant
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /soft/ibm/WebSphere/ProcServer/java/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /data/build/scripts/test.ant with URI = file:///data/build/scripts/test.ant
Project base dir set to: /data/build/scripts
Build sequence for target(s) `build' is [checkDone, step1, step2, fullBuild, noBuild, build]
Complete build sequence is [checkDone, step1, step2, fullBuild, noBuild, build, ]

checkDone:
[available] Found: /tmp/target.file

step1:
    [echo] Executing step1

step2:
    [echo] Executing step2

fullBuild:
Skipped because property 'done' set.

noBuild:
    [echo] Build process skipped, /tmp/target.file already done

build:
    [echo] Build process completed for /tmp/target.file

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

So, what am I missing? Or should I really have an "unless" clause in all the targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common ant gotcha. The if/unless attributes from target don't work with dependency chains.
For the reason see [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) :

> Important: the if and unless attributes only enable or disable the
>   target to which they are attached. They do not control whether or not
>   targets that a conditional target depends upon get executed. In fact,
>   they do not even get evaluated until the target is about to be
>   executed, and all its predecessors have already run.

So you have to use unless attribute also for the stepX targets :

```
<target name="step1" unless="done">
<target name="step2" unless="done">
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what i was doing but it felt so wrong....  I can't understand why the programming world got enamored with that thing when they had good ol' make.

Comment: @xenoid Now we have Gradle :-)

Comment: "Enterprise" in the page title of the Gradle is one word too far :). Usually means "too complicated for what it does". But I will have a look.